# Running for loop over variables or vectors in a matrix, matlab

Tags: matlab, for-loop

I want to construct a for loop over `E` that is some variation of

```
for E = [f f_x f_y]
for i = 1:9
    min(:,i) = linprog(E,[],[],P(i,:),b(i,:),lb,ub_eq(i,:),[],options);
    ub_eq(i+1,:) = ub_eq(i,:) - min(:,i)';
    ub_eq( ub_eq < 0 ) =0;
end
end
```

Where i should be some vector of equal length associated with f f_x or f_y

- Is this possible, and if so how?
- If this is not possible, is it possible to combine f, f_x, and f_y in a matrix and create a for loop over row vectors?

Comment: This is too vague. What are those `f`, `f_x`,  `f_y`? What is the loop content? What does it mean for `i` to be a vector associated with `f`,  `f_x`,  `f_y`?

Comment: `for col = matrix` loops over the matrix columns. Does that help?

Comment: Tried to clarify the question. f is a vector in a linear program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve for iteration over row vectors in a matrix, the code:

```
E = [f; f_x; f_y]    
for e = 1:size(E,1)
    E(e,:)
end
```

will return each individual row vector in `E`